# Is there a way to make file explorer (pinned to task bar) reveal context menu (drop-down of pinned folders) on left click?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

I want to see the drop-down of my pinned folders, instead of opening the Explorer window to Quick access. Akin to list view for docked folders on Mac.

I looked around a bunch, but couldn't find a solution... surprising given the tp software made to mimic the Mac feature.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand with you Question. You want to pin-up your folder into taskbar?If yes

Then give a try with below solution:

> 1) Open you parent location of the folder `Ex: D:/myFolder/abc` . If you want to pin folder `abc` then open location till `myFolder` only.
>
> 2) Now select you folder `abc` by single click on it and hold it.
>
> 3) Now Drag it to taskbar. While you will be dragging it to taskbar. It will show you small tooltip message `Pin to File Explorer` and Drop it.
>
> 4) Now your folder will be pinned in taskbar.

Whenever in future you want to open/view it then just Right Click on File Explorer icon of taskbar and you will be able to see your folder name there.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and thanks. But what I want, in essence, is to make file explorer (that is already pinned to the taskbar) make the right-click action when I left-click on it.  

Like I said before, akin to Mac's docked folder "list" view.

Comment: Hi, Ok got it. I am not sure but I guess this won't be possible bcoz there might be chances have multiple folders pinned in taskbar and all shows under same pinned point. Imagine for a while that this might possible then it would be very hard for OS to understand that which actual folder you want to open out of multiple folder list in pinned folder list. So i think this is not possible. Only workaround is to change mouse Click setting. you can switch invert(left will treat like right and vice-versa) but this will be application for throughout system.

Comment: I don't think you're quite picking up what I'm putting down. Just want to force a folder pinned to the taskbar to right-click action (open context menu) when I left or right click on it... Like setting a default click action for the specific item. I get that it may not be possible, but I don't really get your explanation that it would be difficult for the OS to handle. Changing the setting for the entire system obviously defeats the purpose. Thanks for the input, though.